# Spring not loading CSS and js with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am new to Spring MVC. I create a login page which contains styles and client validation. After the deployment of project i am seeing the login page without any styles and validation. How I can fix this? I have provided my project structure, deployment descriptor and spring configuration file.

I was using `<mvc:resources>` configuration for static contents like img, css, js

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pU13G.png)

> Web .xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-config</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-config</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

`

> spring-config-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">
<context:component-scan base-package="org.fms"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/Resources**" location="/Resources/"/>


<!--View Resolver Configuration-->

<bean id="viewResolver1" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1"/>
    <property name="basename" value="view"/>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver2"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="2"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

> application-context.xml
>   [Application Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXlHR.png)

Comment: Can you show how you are including css, js references in jsp files.

Comment: If mvc:resources mapping is "/Resources/**" then you should include css,js files as <script src="<c:url value="/Resources/js/main.js" />"></script> in jsp

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/Resources/scripts/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/Resources/scripts/css/style2.css"/>">
    <script src="<c:url value="/Resources/scripts/jquery.min.js"/>"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Srikanth

Issue was with resource folder structure. I have restructure the resource folder to be

resources
  --css
  --js
  --images

After this change my page loaded properly.